How to set path to application to open via URI scheme launch macOS
I just want to clarify that I’m not looking how to associate an application with a URI scheme. There are posts about this and they work however my issue is that I am developing an app that uses a URI scheme to open. Now on any machine that only has one copy of the application installed, it works fine.
My issue is that on my development machine, there are copies of the app in the Archives, DerivedData, maybe Applications folder as well.
When I build my app, the current build is in my DerivedData. When I try to launch my app using a URI launch, it sometimes opens the copy in the Archives folder, sometimes other places.
I am hoping someone can help me locate somewhere I can define which copy of my application to launch on URI launch.

Strongly suggest adjusting your workflow so that you use different bundle IDs/URIs to differentiate between development versions, prod versions, etc. Then, keep one version of the executable tied to a certain URI.

I agreed with @jnpdx...
One approach would be to make a "URL-forwarding app", that is the only receiver of the URL, and then sends it to the correct binary...
(occurred to me because I was reading xcode-select docs today)
